# How do I calculate the percentage to add to a credit card invoice?

Tags: credit-card

If I send someone an invoice for $150 and put a credit card surcharge of 2.4% ($3.60) on the invoice, then I end up paying 2.4% of $153.60 which is $3.68. I don't actually get my original $150.00 invoice amount; I get $149.92, which isn't a big deal for small sums but it's starting to add up.

Is there an easy way to calculate what the surcharge is so that I get the total $150 into my bank account?

Comment: You want to charge so that price*0.976 = 150.00   or 150.00/0.976   or $153.69

Comment: Thanks @mhoran_psprep if you'd like to put that in as an answer I'll mark it as correct - thanks again!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to charge so that:

```
price*0.976 = $150.00
```

now with a little algebra.

```
price = $150.00/0.976 
price =  $153.6885
```

Rounded up to $153.69

Comment: A better way to represent this would be 1/0.976 = 1.0246 or 2.46%. So 2.46% on $150 would be $3.69 (as above).